# Getting Program received signal: “SIGKILL” when closing my application in multi tasking bar in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am getting Program received signal:  “SIGKILL” Exception when I close my application in multitasking bar of my device.Can anyone suggest me why this happening and how to resolve it?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: Are you talking about iOS or Mac here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are experiencing a Snow Leopard feature?

> To support improved shutdown, your application needs to mark itself as “dirty” or “clean,” depending on whether it has unsaved changes and needs to do work before quitting, or can be terminated without further notice. When the system shuts down, clean applications are terminated (via SIGKILL) without further interaction.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_6.html -> Improved Shutdown